# Duplicate element ID's dynamically?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, hide, element, show

My script dynamically generates multiple unlimited show/hide areas as displayed as an example below. I need to figure out how to automatically create ID's, and  then duplicate each along the way. Example: ID1/ID1, ID2/ID2, etc.

I hope someone understands what I am trying to do. I'm not code literate enough to explain it any better. Even if each ID is random but duplicated, that will work.

Thank you!

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('ID1')">TEST</a>
<div id="ID1" style="display: none;">
CONTENT HERE
</div>

<a href="javascript:toggle('ID2')">TEST</a>
<div id="ID2" style="display: none;">
CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

Javascript Portion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(element) {
document.getElementById(element).style.display = (document.getElementById(element).style.display == "none") ? "" : "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: _"My script dynamically generates multiple unlimited show/hide areas"_ - Please show the relevant part of your script, not just its (current or desired) output.

Comment: So you'd like to make an `ID3`, `ID4`, `ID5` (...), each with their own link and div?

Comment: I've added the javascript portion for you nnnnnn

Comment: Qantas 94 Heavy... yup but duplicate each ID for each field... ID3/ID3, ID4/ID4, ID5/ID5, etc. It needs to automatically copy the ID from the "toggle("... to the ID of the "div id="...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery, you don't need to care about the IDs at all.

```
<a href="javascript:;">TEST</a>
<div id="ID1" style="display: none;">
CONTENT HERE
</div>

<a href="javascript:;">TEST</a>
<div id="ID2" style="display: none;">
CONTENT HERE
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
       $(this).next('div').toggle() 
    });
});
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vPmE5/

Comment: Thanks TrungDQ.... that's closer, however I need the ID's to be randomly generated or incremented automatically via javascript since the code you posted will end up being rendered on a html page ... I wish I could output it in a php page I could add some php code to get the ID values needed but unfortunately I can't. Or when you say I don't need to worry about the ID's, does that mean the <div id=".... can all be the same? ID1, ID1, ID1?

Comment: The IDs don't affect the jQuery script at all, you can delete them in my example, still work. You may want to learn about jquery to know what happened in the script, it actually does the "toggle()" for the next div element.

Comment: Don't got time to learn... just need this up and running asap. Thanks for your help. I'll play around with what you gave me.

Comment: I owe you a beer or something TrungDQ! Thanks so much. Worked flawlessly.... I would vote you up if I could :)